# How to use the "result" from <sql:query var="result">

Tags: sql, jstl

I have this code:

```
<sql:query var="result" 
sql="select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='userdb';"
/>
```

What does `result` store and how can I use it to retrieve my data?

Answer (score 0):

The [`<sql:query>` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/sql/query.html) explains what's inside the `result` variable:

> The type of the scoped variable is javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.Result

The `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.Result` is a sort of wrapper over a `java.sql.ResultSet` and [has methods to get to the rows of data](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/sql/Result.html). It's then just a matter of `<c:forEach>`ing the rows. See [here](http://software.it168.com/manual/servlet/0596005725_jsvltjspckbk-chp-23-sect-7.html) for an example.

P.S. Unless used for prototyping your application, using JSTL's SQL tags to access the database from within the JSP is discouraged.